# pyautogui Python 3.6 interact with ok button

Tags: python, pyautogui

I want to use the pyautogui.alert function and i want a special action to be done after the user clicks the OK button. How can i interact with this button?

```
pyautogui.alert (text = '', title = '', button = 'OK')
```

Answer (score 2):

Or you can do this:

```
# display the alert
alert = pyautogui.alert(text = '', title = '', button = 'OK')
# check to see if "OK" was pressed
if alert.upper() == "OK":
    # do something
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation of pyAutoGUI,

`Alert() Displays a simple message box with text and a single button. Returns the text of the button clicked on.`

If you want to trigger some action when user clicks the OK button, you can store result of button press in a variable and check it with a condition.

```
pressed=pyautogui.alert(text='', title='', button='OK')
if(pressed=='OK'):
    #DO SOMETHING
```